# Custom UITableViewCell with optionals

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm creating custom cell for my `tableView`. I made a swift file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CellForPost: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var postLikes: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postPhoto: UIImageView!
}
```

and implemented it in delegate method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellForPost
    cell.postPhoto.image = UIImage.init(data: (posts[indexPath.item].postPhoto)! as NSData)
    cell.postText.text = posts[indexPath.item].postText
    cell.postLikes.text = String(posts[indexPath.item].postLikes!)
    cell.postDate.text = timestampToDate(posts[indexPath.item].postDate!)
    return cell
}
```

everything works great when post has full content, but when for example there is no photo(which is optional in `post` struct) it crashes with message

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I understand this message, so I tried to make

```
@IBOutlet weak var postPhoto: UIImageView?
```

like an optional value, but it doesn't work, 'cos compiler wants me to **unwrap** values before inserting to cell. 
P.S. If it's possible to give a short advice about deleting `imageView` at all when it is nil and resize row height to fit.

Comment: Just a small addition: `func tableView(tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:)` is a data source method, not a delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need touch your outlets declarations, you need check for nil in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (and setup nil as value thought)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellForPost

    var image: UIImage? = nil
    if let imageData = posts[indexPath.item].postPhoto {
        image = UIImage.init(data: imageData)
    }
    cell.postPhoto.image = image

    cell.postText.text = posts[indexPath.item].postText

    var postLikes: String? = nil
    if let likesData = posts[indexPath.item].postLikes {
        postLikes = String(likesData)
    }
    cell.postLikes.text = postLikes

    var postDate: String? = nil
    if let dateData = posts[indexPath.item].postDate {
        postDate = timestampToDate(dateData)
    }
    cell.postDate.text = postDate

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Error: 'Downcast from "NSData?" to "NSData" only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use "!"?'

Comment: @JohnMurcielago remove  `as? NSData` then. Its not obvious from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that your object has value before assigning it to the `IBOutelet`. You need to change your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` something like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellForPost
    if let data = posts[indexPath.item].postPhoto) as? NSData {
        cell.postPhoto.image = UIImage.init(data: data)
    }
    else {
        cell.postPhoto.image = nil
    }
    if let postText = posts[indexPath.item].postText) as? String {
        cell.postText.text = postText
    }
    else {
        cell.postText.text = ""
    }
    if let postLikes = posts[indexPath.item].postLikes) as? Int {
        cell.postLikes.text = String(postLikes)
    }
    else {
        cell.postLikes.text = ""
    }
    if let postDate = posts[indexPath.item].postDate) as? NSDate {
        cell.postDate.text = timestampToDate(postDate)
    }
    else {
        cell.postDate.text = ""
    }
    return cell
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Your code contain strong mistakes. You are not overriding old values if nil become in some fields, so cell will show random data from previous appearing. Also it will not even compile due syntax mistakes

Comment: Your code still have syntax mistakes and wont compile, and I still don't like it because for some unnecessary reason you are trying to guess data types (Int and NSDate) instead simple unwrap; thought, code already closer to my answer.